# Pdf preview of html page javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm trying to create a pdf preview on a new page in javascript of an HTML page by clicking a button.

What I would like to have is that by clicking this button on the page, it will open a new tab on the browser which contains the pdf preview of the source page and from there I would download the pdf.

At this moment I've used this code

```
function printopen() {
    var w = window.open();
    var html = $("#divtoprint").html();
    $(w.document.body).html(html);
    w.print();
}
```

which opens a new blank page and the pop-up. I don't want to show the pop-up but the appropriate download button and the page should contain the pdf preview.

What would be the correct way to achieve this?

Comment: You need a JS library to convert HTML to PDF, if you do not already have the PDF.

Answer (score 0):

This will open the pdf preview in a new tab and you can download it too.

In your window.open give the path to your ressource as parameter https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open

```
 function printopen(){

                var w = window.open("path_to_your_file");
                var html = $("#divtoprint").html();
                  $(w.document.body).html(html);
                  w.print();
              }
```

But keep in mind it's not guarantated the user can decide if tabs will apear in a new tab or not.

Comment: If I press crtl+p on my page I'll get a pdf preview. Is possible to have that preview on a new tab without getting that pop up?

Comment: For me this seems to be something user based like open in a new tab or not. 
I think you can decide how the pdf will be displayed in your browser settings.

Comment: I agree with that but is what the client asked me